# SQL: division by specific records when calculating the average (AVG) and not for all

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite

I would like to calculate the average of the goals conceded only in the matches away from Chelsea, therefore field `team_away=Chelsea`, but of the matches limited to the `1st  round` and the `2nd round`.

PROBLEM: I can limit the records with `LIMIT`, but the problem is that the division (the division for calculating the average after adding the goals conceded (`score_home`)) occurs incorrectly, because it divides by all the records where team_away=Chelsea (round 2, 4, 5). Instead I would like to divide only by the number of selected records in which `team_away=Chelsea` is present (in the table example, only round 2)

Information is never fixed, so I would like to achieve this:

Search if Chelsea is team_away (`team_away=Chelsea`) in the `1st round` and in the `2nd round`, then:

- If Chelsea is `team_away` only in `round 1`, then `score_home / 1`
- If Chelsea is `team_away` only in `round 2`, then `score_home / 1`
- If Chelsea is `team_away` in both rounds, then `(score_home for round 1 + score_home for round 2) / 2`
- If Chelsea is never `team_away` in the first two days, then no average

Obviously in the future I will add more rounds, so the code must be designed to work with many rounds and not just 2.

| id | round | team_home | team_away | score_home | score_away |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 5 | Liverpool | CHELSEA | 3 | 2 |
|  | 4 | United | CHELSEA | 0 | 1 |
|  | 3 | Leeds | Brighton | 1 | 3 |
|  | 2 | Tottenham | CHELSEA | 2 | 2 |
|  | 1 | Arsenal | Fulham | 2 | 0 |

```
cursor_test.execute("""
     SELECT AVG(score_home) 

         FROM (SELECT score_home
                   FROM Results
                   WHERE team_away=?
                   ORDER BY round DESC
                   LIMIT 2;)
      """,(Team_Away))
```

Comment: You shouldn't have `;` inside the subquery. That can only be at the end of the query, and it's optional there.

Comment: @Barmar Yes you are right. Small careless error while writing code on Stackoverflow. I don't actually use it there. However, could you help me with the question? I think the solution is quite simple, perhaps I went a little long in the explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subquery that gets the first 2 rounds should not filter by `team_away`, it should use the entire table. Then you can filter by team after joining with that.

```
SELECT AVG(res.score_home)
FROM Results AS res
JOIN (
    SELECT round
    FROM Results
    ORDER BY round
    LIMIT 2
) AS rd ON res.round = rd.round
WHERE res.team_away = ?
```

The `rd` subquery will return only rounds 1 and 2. When you then join this with `Result` and filter by `res.team_away = ?`, you'll just get round 2 for `CHELSEA`.

Comment: Wow, quick response, thanks :) I'll test the code now. I don't understand what you mean by "When you then join this with Result and filter by res.team_away = ?, you'll just get round 2 for CHELSEA"? Can you explain better please? Thank you

Comment: The join reduces the rows to just round = 1 and round = 2. The `WHERE` then reduces this to just round 2, because that's the only one with `team_away = 'CHELSEA'`

Comment: There is something wrong with your code, but I can't understand :( I tested your code with both LIMIT 1 (average of only 1 round with team_away) and with LIMIT 2 (1 round and 2 rounds). Using it only for 1 round everything is ok, the averages print correctly. While using it for 2 rounds (LIMIT 2), I get all NULL in the database column (where I update the average results)

Comment: It works correctly for me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2rMEmL1tMNWkqD7Qd5UiFu/0

Comment: It will fail for LIMIT 1 since that will just return round = 1, and there's no team_away = CHELSEA there.

Comment: That corresponds to your last bullet point.

Comment: In theory yes. I'm trying to change Chelsea's order to test better. I have to get the average both for just the 1 round and for 2 rounds (1 and 2). So I'm doing various tests with both LIMIT 1 and LIMIT 2 (changing the order in the database). The code in the link you pasted seems right. So it was probably my mistake. I still continue to test. I'll answer you shortly (obviously I will vote and accept your answer). See you later

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255354/discussion-between-evangelos-dellas-and-barmar).